# AWS Policies explained?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-policies

I am learning AWS and I have the following task in an online training course:

> Configure the MongoDB VM as highly privileged – configure an instance
> profile to the VM and add the permission “ec2:*” as a custom policy.

I am trying to work out what that means. Is the task asking for a role that enables the VM instance to have full control over all EC2 resources?

If I understand it correctly, then I think the following policy would implement it.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance"
        }
    ]
}
```

My understanding is that this policy is saying any EC2 instance can perform any EC2 action. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are `almost` correct. Roles are attached to individual services which means your **particular VM** can perform any Ec2 action on this resource `arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance`.

There is a difference in saying any ec2 can perform ec2 action instead that **ec2 instance can perform any ec2 action to which this role is attached.**

Comment: Glad it helped, If this helped you, invite/acceptance would be appreciated so that it helped others in the future.

Comment: No, it is saying that the instance (by using that IAM Role) can perform **any EC2 action that involves an instance**. For example, it cannot create a Security Group, because that requires an ARN in the format `arn:aws:ec2:*:security-group/*`, which does not match `arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance`. It could, however, call `StopInstances()` since that involves an instance.